# how to map with flask api

Tags: python, api, flask, mapping

The mapping in my api is not working. I have an api with a endpoint sign-in. When there is a GET the return value is a message. I get a 404 error.

The are three files apis.py, sign_in.py and run.py

In the apis.py file there are all the routes defined. In sign_in.py there is the GET en POST defined. In run.py is the start of the application.

apis.py

```
api_blueprint = Blueprint('api', __name__)
api = Api(api_blueprint)




# Route
api.add_namespace(sign_in_namespace,'/sign-in')
api.add_namespace(user_namespace,'/<string:username>')
api.add_namespace(AccessPointResource_namespace,'/access-points')
api.add_namespace(NewAddedAccessPointResource_namespace,'/access-points/new')
api.add_namespace(AllAccessPointResource_namespace,'/access-points/all')
api.add_namespace(AccessPointResourceById_namespace,'/access-points/<int:id>')
api.add_namespace(AccessPointResourceByIdWithData_namespace,'/access-points/<id>/data')
api.add_namespace(all_data_acquisition_namespace,'/data/all')
api.add_namespace(by_id_data_acquisition_namespace,'/data/<id>')
```

sign_in.py

```
sign_in_namespace = Namespace('sign-in', description='sign in page')

@sign_in_namespace.route("")
class SignInResource(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {"message": "Retrieves the sign in resource"}
    def post(self):
        return {"message": "Signs the user in, create access token and check if user has the correct policy to access the application"}
```

I expect the message defined in sign_in.py but I get the following message from swagger.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `@sign_in_namespace.route("")` be `@sign_in_namespace.route("/")` (with a slash to clearly denote your controller lives at the root)? It may solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I had to add `path='sign-in'` in `sign_in_namespace = Namespace('sign-in', path='sign-in', description='sign in page')`